# Use Array of Values of Object in a Foreach Loop

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach

I cannot seem to find anything about using the *values* of one property of an object in a foreach loop (without having the entire object placed into the loop).

I first create a function called UFGet-Servers that uses Get-ADComputer and returns the names of the servers in a specific OU in my environment and places them in an array.  That's great, except that when I use the array in a foreach loop, each object that it grabs has @[Name=serverName] in it, which I cannot use in any useful manner. The following pseudo-code is an abbreviated example:

```
foreach($Computer in $ComputerNames){do code... code is adding the server name into a UNC path such as "\\$Computer\C$\"}
```

The problem with the above is that you can't add the whole object to a path -- it ends up looking like "\@[Name=serverNameHere]\C$\" which totally bombs out.  How do I get rid of the "@[property=" part, and simply use the value as the $Computer in the loop?

What really weirds me out is that I can't find a straightforward article on this anywhere... would have thought everyone and their mom would have wanted to do something like this.

Comment: Sounds like your function actually returns an array of hashtables instead of an array of strings.  Try referring to `$Computer.Name` or `$Computer.Item('Name')` or `$Computer['Name']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, your issue isn't with ForEach loops, it is with string formatting. There are two ways that I know of to take care of what you need. First is going to be string formatting, which allows you to use `{0}`m `{1}` and so on to inject values into a string, providing that you follow the string with -f and a list of said values. Such as:

```
ForEach($Computer in $ComputerNames){
    "The Server Path is \\{0}\Share$" -f $Computer.Name
}
```

The second way is a sub-expression (I'm sure somebody will correct me if I used the wrong term there). This one involves enclosing the variable and desired property (or a function, or whatever) inside `$()`. This will evaluate whatever is inside the parenthesis before evaluating the string. See my example:

```
ForEach($Computer in $ComputerNames){
    "The Server Path is \\$($Computer.name)\Share$"
}
```

Comment: I like the latter option the best.  Thanks! I new something like this had to exist, but I am, quite frankly, a noob, so this really helped.  Whole script works now (and that was the last problem section of a larger script).